# How to deserialize xml into Dictionary when key is the Xml node name?

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

Here is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TransactionLog>
  <RuleViolations>
    <error>
      <message>error1</message>
      <keys>
        <key1>val1</key1>
        <key2>val2</key2>
        <key3>val3</key3>
        <key4>val4</key4>
      </keys>
    </error>
    <error>
      <message>error1</message>
      <keys>
        <key1>val5</key1>
        <key2>val6</key2>
      </keys>
    </error>
    <error>
      <message>error3</message>
      <keys>
        <key2>val7</key2>
        <key3>val8</key3>
        <key4>val9</key4>
      </keys>
    </error>
  </RuleViolations>
</TransactionLog>
```

What I have now:

```
[XmlRoot("TransactionLog")]
public class TransactionLogModel
{
    [XmlArray("RuleViolations")]
    [XmlArrayItem("error")]
    public List<KeyValuePair<string,string>> RuleViolations { get; set; }
}
```

But how can we serialize the `<keys>` section?

---

The closest SO post I can find is here: [Deserialize XML into Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210059/deserialize-xml-into-dictionarystring-string)

But I am not using `XDocument`.

```
var x = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TransactionLogModel));
var model = (TransactionLogModel)x.Deserialize(new StringReader(log));
```

How can we deserialize this xml in `XmlSerializer`?

Comment: What should be the content of the deserialized class? I don't understand where you want the keys to end up in your model.

Comment: the key1, key2... are dynamic? if so you should look into this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13353387/generic-xml-deserialization-into-undefined-objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your data model doesn't match your XML -- there are several intermediate classes missing between `TransactionLog` and `keys`.  Instead, it should look something like:

```
[XmlRoot("TransactionLog")]
public class TransactionLogModel
{
    [XmlElement("RuleViolations")]
    public List<RuleViolation> RuleViolations { get; set; }
}

public class RuleViolation
{
    public RuleViolation() { this.Errors = new List<Error>(); }

    [XmlElement("error")]
    public List<Error> Errors { get; set; }
}

public class Error
{
    [XmlElement("message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    // To be done.
    public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Keys { get; set; }
}
```

Next, to serialize the `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Keys` using the key names as element names, the standard solution is to [implement `IXmlSerializable`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279534/proper-way-to-implement-ixmlserializable) on an appropriate type.  It's a bit of a nuisance but not awful since your pair values are primitive types (strings) rather that complex types requiring nested serializations.

For instance, you could use the `XmlKeyTextValueListWrapper` from [Serialize Dictionary member to XML elements and data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29795747/serialize-dictionarystring-string-member-to-xml-elements-and-data):

```
public class XmlKeyTextValueListWrapper<TValue> : CollectionWrapper<KeyValuePair<string, TValue>>, IXmlSerializable
{
    public XmlKeyTextValueListWrapper() : base(new List<KeyValuePair<string, TValue>>()) { } // For deserialization.

    public XmlKeyTextValueListWrapper(ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, TValue>> baseCollection) : base(baseCollection) { }

    public XmlKeyTextValueListWrapper(Func<ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, TValue>>> getCollection) : base(getCollection) {}

    #region IXmlSerializable Members

    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(TValue));
        XmlKeyValueListHelper.ReadXml(reader, this, converter);
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(TValue));
        XmlKeyValueListHelper.WriteXml(writer, this, converter);
    }

    #endregion
}

public static class XmlKeyValueListHelper
{
    public static void WriteXml<T>(XmlWriter writer, ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, T>> collection, TypeConverter typeConverter)
    {
        foreach (var pair in collection)
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement(XmlConvert.EncodeName(pair.Key));
            writer.WriteValue(typeConverter.ConvertToInvariantString(pair.Value));
            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
    }

    public static void ReadXml<T>(XmlReader reader, ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, T>> collection, TypeConverter typeConverter)
    {
        if (reader.IsEmptyElement)
        {
            reader.Read();
            return;
        }

        reader.ReadStartElement(); // Advance to the first sub element of the list element.
        while (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
        {
            var key = XmlConvert.DecodeName(reader.Name);
            string value;
            if (reader.IsEmptyElement)
            {
                value = string.Empty;
                // Move past the end of item element
                reader.Read();
            }
            else
            {
                // Read content and move past the end of item element
                value = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
            }
            collection.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,T>(key, (T)typeConverter.ConvertFromInvariantString(value)));
        }
        // Move past the end of the list element
        reader.ReadEndElement();
    }

    public static void CopyTo<TValue>(this XmlKeyTextValueListWrapper<TValue> collection, ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, TValue>> dictionary)
    {
        if (dictionary == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("dictionary");
        if (collection == null)
            dictionary.Clear();
        else
        {
            if (collection.IsWrapperFor(dictionary)) // For efficiency
                return;
            var pairs = collection.ToList();
            dictionary.Clear();
            foreach (var item in pairs)
                dictionary.Add(item);
        }
    }
}

public class CollectionWrapper<T> : ICollection<T>
{
    readonly Func<ICollection<T>> getCollection;

    public CollectionWrapper(ICollection<T> baseCollection)
    {
        if (baseCollection == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        this.getCollection = () => baseCollection;
    }

    public CollectionWrapper(Func<ICollection<T>> getCollection)
    {
        if (getCollection == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        this.getCollection = getCollection;
    }

    public bool IsWrapperFor(ICollection<T> other)
    {
        if (other == Collection)
            return true;
        var otherWrapper = other as CollectionWrapper<T>;
        return otherWrapper != null && otherWrapper.IsWrapperFor(Collection);
    }

    ICollection<T> Collection { get { return getCollection(); } }

    #region ICollection<T> Members

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        Collection.Add(item);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        Collection.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        return Collection.Contains(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        Collection.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return Collection.Count; }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return Collection.IsReadOnly; }
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        return Collection.Remove(item);
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable<T> Members

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Collection.GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable Members

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Then use it like:

```
public class Error
{
    [XmlElement("message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> keys;

    [XmlIgnore]
    public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Keys
    {
        get
        {
            // Ensure keys is never null.
            return (keys = keys ?? new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>());
        }
        set
        {
            keys = value;
        }
    }

    [XmlElement("keys")]
    [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never), DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    public XmlKeyTextValueListWrapper<string> XmlKeys
    {
        get
        {
            return new XmlKeyTextValueListWrapper<string>(() => this.Keys);
        }
        set
        {
            value.CopyTo(Keys);
        }
    }
}
```

Incidentally, the same solution will work with a `public Dictionary<string, string> Keys` property, just be sure that the dictionary is pre-allocated:

```
public class Error
{
    [XmlElement("message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    Dictionary<string, string> keys;

    [XmlIgnore]
    public Dictionary<string, string> Keys
    {
        get
        {
            // Ensure keys is never null.
            return (keys = keys ?? new Dictionary<string, string>());
        }
        set
        {
            keys = value;
        }
    }

    [XmlElement("keys")]
    [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never), DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    public XmlKeyTextValueListWrapper<string> XmlKeys
    {
        get
        {
            return new XmlKeyTextValueListWrapper<string>(() => this.Keys);
        }
        set
        {
            value.CopyTo(Keys);
        }
    }
}
```